# Embedding videos from my site on Facebook profile

Tags: facebook, html5-video, share, facebook-opengraph

I own a video site. I need to share one video on my site on Facebook embedding it on the timeline, just like Youtube does. When a Facebook user clicks on the preview image on my Facebook profile my player should open into the timeline and the video should play without opening a new page.

I'm using flowplayer on a Wordpress site. Of course I used OG: tags. This is my `<head>` code:

```html
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="123456789101112"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="video"/>
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="640">
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="385">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mysite.com/videogallery/title/"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="title"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Some description"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mysite.com/link-to-image.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg"> 
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.mysite.com/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf?config={%22playerId%22:%22player%22,%22clip%22:{%22url%22:%22http://www.mysite.com/link-to-video.mp4%22},%22playlist%22:[{%22url%22:%22http://www.mysite.com/link-to-video.mp4%22}]}" />
```

I'm noticing a very strange thing: I have more than one Facebook account and I can see the embedded video just like I want it with one of these accounts. I only can see the preview image and the simple link to my site with the other ones.

Comment: Is this happening because of the https:// connection?? I think so. Should I inevitably have a https site to do this?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I am also facing the same problem